# Confirm that $E_x(a)=\frac{kQ}{ a \sqrt{a^2+L^2}}$

Tags: calculus

A total charge of Q is distributed uniformly on a line segment of length 2L along the y-axis. The x-component of the electric field at a point (a, 0)
is given by.

$$E_x(a) = \frac{kQa}{2L} \times \int_{-L}^{L} \frac{dy}{(a^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$

Confirm that 
$$E_x(a) = \frac{kQ}{ a \sqrt{a^2+L^2}}.$$

Can anybody explain what this problem is asking and how to solve it?
Also, can somebody format my equations? I'd be forever grateful. I'm not sure how to do it.

(Note: I replaced the $=$ in front of the integral with a $\times$)

The questions is computing the actual value of the $x$ component of the $E$ field vector that is produced by a continuous charged line segment using the explicit computation of an integral (in the case of discrete point charges this would be a sum).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the integral has the easy to confirm anti-derivative 
$$I(y)= \frac{y}{a^2\sqrt{y^2+a^2}}$$
and therefore you get
$$E_x(a) = \frac{kQa}{2L} \times \int_{-L}^{L} \frac{dy}{(a^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$

$$=\frac{kQa}{2L} \Big(I(L)-I(-L)\Big)$$
$$=\frac{kQa}{2L} \Big(\frac{L}{a^2\sqrt{L^2+a^2}}-\frac{-L}{a^2\sqrt{L^2+a^2}} \Big)$$
$$E_x(a)=\frac{kQ}{ a \sqrt{a^2+L^2}}.$$